# json load only a single key value pair from all observations - python

Tags: python, json

I have very large json files from which I would like to get a single key-value pair of all observations.
eg.:

```
{"name":"John", "rollno":4}
```

Suppose i have 10000 observations like this, I would like to extract only `rollno` from all the 10000 observations. How do I do this at the time of loading the file using `json.load()`

Comment: I think the rollno is supposed to be in quotes

Comment: @alexpdev yep, i just put it as an example

Comment: THis isn't really possible because the json parser, needs the full json object. It doesn't work incrementally.  Also any kind of custom solution that did parse the document extracting only the "rollno" values wouldn't actually perform any quicker because it would still need to read in the whole file in order to determine where the values were

Answer (score 1):

To extract just the `rollno` values, you would still need to extract all the json data from the file, then iterate the data and store the `rollno` values in a separate structure.

```
data = json.load(open(filepath))
rollnos = [observation['rollno'] for observation in data]
```

Comment: yeah, I get this. i glossed over  the docs, couldn't find anything.  It's just that i have many such files, and this would've made my job easier